# Angular momentum, rotating cylinders,...

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, rotations

Revising, this is what I'm stuck on: inertia tensors, rotating rigid bodies about axis other than its axis of symmety,...

I think it'd help a lot to see a worked example and I can't find anything on the web.
Here is my example:

Considering a cylinder of unit density occupying the region x²+y²<=a², 0<=z<=h, what is its angular momentum about the axis x=z,y=0? Can you explain to me how to get there? This is very general so I think I'll be able to generalize it when I understand this one!

Any help would be amazing! Thank you

Comment: Are we given an angular velocity? Is it simply a matter of finding the object's [moment of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia)?

Comment: Yes, it is with a given angular velocity, v say. Hum... maybe but I can't say, I really don't get it :/